# 以下のようなデータを取得したい場合のSQL文は？

Tags: sql

sqlが得意ではないので教えていただきたいです。

以下の契約情報TBLから「契約者ID_PK」「所属県番号」を抽出したいです。
抽出条件は、契約者IDごとの重複しない所属県番号の一覧です。
よろしくお願いします。

◾️契約情報TBL

```
契約者ID_PK  契約番号_PK  所属県番号  …
aaa                 001                 01
aaa                 002                 01
aaa                 003                 02
bbb                 001                 01
bbb                 002                 02
bbb                 003                 02
ccc                 001                 01
ccc                 002                 01
ccc                 003                 01
```

◾️取得したいデータ

```
契約者ID  所属県番号
aaa          01
aaa          02
bbb          01
bbb          02
ccc          01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 契約者ID_PK, 所属県番号 FROM 契約情報TBL
```

ですかね。`DISTINCT` を使うと結果から重複する行が削除されます。